# React component does not update after Redux store changes

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-saga, use-effect

I am trying to fetch some data in a react component using the `useEffect` hook. After the initial render, `fetchItems()` gets the items and updates the store. However, `items` is still an empty object even after the store updates.

I might be using `useEffects` wrong. How do you use Redux with `useEffects`? I want to set a loading state for the component, but since the component only dispatches an action to fetch items (instead of directly calling the API), it does not know when the data is fetched and the store is updated so it can pull it.

Can someone please help figure out how to make sure that `items` object is updated after the saga fetch and the subsequent store update?

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const ItemComponent = ({ item, fetchItem }) => {
    const { itemId } = useParams();
    
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        setIsLoading(true)
        fetchItem(itemId)
        setIsLoading(false)
    }, []);
    
    console.log(item) // gives empty object even after the fetch and store update
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    item: state.item
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        fetchItem: (itemId) => { dispatch(fetchItemActionCreator(itemId)) }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ItemComponent);
```

- `fetchItemActionCreator` is an action creator that creates the action to be dispatched.
- My reducer and saga work fine as I can see the store actions and updates in the console.
- If I pass the `items` object into the dependency array for `useEffect`, then there will be an infinite loop and the page keeps re-rendering.

Reducer:

```js
const itemReducer = (state={}, { type, payload }) => { 
  switch(type) { 
  case ITEM_GET_SUCCESS: 
    return {...state, ...payload} 
  default: return state 
  } 
}
```

fetchItemActionCreator:

```js
import { createAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const fetchItemActionCreator = createAction(ITEM_GET_PENDING);
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Could you share your `item reducer` and and  `fetchItemActionCreator `

Comment: `const ItemComponent = ({ item , fetchItem}) => {` Is that accidental?

Comment: Just added the reducer and action creator. And yes, the `fetchItem` was accidentally not added here in the question

Answer (score 1):

> I want to set a loading state for the component

```
/** Action */
const getItem = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: 'GET_ITEM_START' });

  axios
    .get('your api end point')
    .then(res => {
      const item = res.data;
      dispatch({
        type: 'GET_ITEM_SUCCESS',
        payload: {
          item,
        },
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'GET_ITEM_FAIL',
        payload: error,
      });
    });
};

/** Reducer */
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  item: null,
  error: '',
  loading: false,
};

const itemReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'GET_ITEM_START':
      return { ...state, error: '', loading: true };

    case 'GET_ITEM_SUCCESS':
      return { ...state, ...payload, loading: false };

    case 'GET_ITEM_FAIL':
      return { ...state, error: payload, loading: false };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**Then your could handle Loading state in your component**

```
  const ItemComponent = ({ fetchItem, item, loading, error }) => {
    /** ... */
    /**
      Check for loading and show a spinner or anything like that
    */

    useEffect(() => {
      fetchItem(itemId);
    }, []);

    if (loading) return <ActivityIndicator />;
    if (item) return <View>{/* renderItem */}</View>;
    return null;
  };
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this @Hend El-Sahli. Is there a way to do this with the `useEffect`? Would you need to pull in data in the component itself?

Comment: Thank you for the update, @Hend El-Sahli. I was wondering, do I not need to pass `itemId` to the dependency array of `useEffect`?